# AngularJS: Adding to a directive's scope in the link method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that inherits the parent's scope, but I get the sense that it's bad to extend the parent scope within the link method.

```
angular.module('someModule', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/my-template.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.newModel = ['a'];  // newModel not defined in parent scope
      }
    };
  });
```

Does defining a new model on the scope `newModel` go against AngularJS principles of scoping? I couldn't find any examples online that approve/discourage this behavior. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember directives are reusable piece of functionality. Changing the scope object on which directive is defined may lead to side affect if the parent itself defines similar fields. This can happen if you use the directive in multiple places and\or pages. So keep that in mind.

The two improvement that can be done are

1. Use `scope:true` in directive definition, which creates a child scope and you can add you properties to child scope, but remember nothing still stops you from manipulating parent scope objects.
2. Use isolated scopes `scope:{newModel:'='}`, this does not mess with parent scope and you achieve maximum re-usability, but all access to parent scope object have to be provided through the isolated scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the primitive value on parent scope.

In that case you can:

1. Define function in parent scope like setter which will change the value of your primitive

   `$scope.setNewModel = function(newVal) {
       $scope.newModel = newVal;
    }`
2. Use `$parent.newModel = 'newValue'`

and useful to read https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: In this case, there is no child scope created so, the argument does not hold good. Directive scope is same as parent scope.

Comment: yes beacuse by default it scope:false, I forgot mention what we need setted scope:true :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with initializing scope inside your link function.

Personally, I would initialize scope within the directive's controller - but that is a matter of preference.